# Convert decimal time to minutes in SAS

Tags: time, sas, decimal

I am having trouble converting a 9.3 decimal variable to minutes.  The variable is showing as a fraction of an hour and I need that to show as minutes.

Here is an example below of what needs to be converted.

```
DECSNTIME
0.039
1.279
6.801
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to multiply the number by 60 to get minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the decimal hours to seconds, and format the value for time display.

```
data have;
  input decsntime @@;
  cards;
0.039 1.279 6.801
run;

data want;
  set have;
  minutes = decsntime * 60; * plain minutes might be enough, depends on analysis;
  time = decsntime * 3600; * sas time value;
  format time time5.;
run;

proc report data=want;
  columns decsntime minutes time time=timehms time=timehmsd;
  define decsntime / 'Time/(hours)' display;
  define time / 'Time/(H:M)';
  define timehms / format=time8. 'Time/(H:M:S)';
  define timehmsd / format=time11.2 'Time/(H:M:S.D)';
run;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment by @Richard are you looking for something as simple as the following? If not then please edit your question to give more explanation and examples of data before and after the conversion from hours to minutes.

```
data have;
   input hours;
   datalines;
9.3
0.039
1.279
6.801
1
1.5
2
;

data want;
   set have;
   minutes = hours * 60;
run;
```